# What packages does 1) Java and 2) Groovy automatically import?

Tags: java, groovy, import

Having programmed in Groovy quite a bit I know classes in certain packages are automatically imported. What's the scoop for 1) Java and 2) Groovy?
Is there a definitive list of ones you don't need to specify an import for for each of these languages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Java, the only package imported by default is

```
java.lang.*
```

This is where objects such as String and Object reside.

According to [here](https://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_default_imports), the list of packages for groovy are

```
java.io.*
java.lang.*
java.math.BigDecimal
java.math.BigInteger
java.net.*
java.util.*
groovy.lang.*
groovy.util.*
```

Comment: Java also automatically imports the current package.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, java only imports

```
java.lang.*
```

wheras groovy imports:

```
java.io.*
java.lang.*
java.math.BigDecimal
java.math.BigInteger
java.net.*
java.util.*
groovy.lang.*
groovy.util.*
```

According to https://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_default_imports

Answer (score -1):

According to [The Groovy programming language - Program structure](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html)

Groovy by default imports these classes for you. There are six packages that groovy imports for you, they are:

```
import java.lang.*
import java.util.*
import java.io.*
import java.net.*
import groovy.lang.*
import groovy.util.*
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.math.BigDecimal
```