# Reserved Class Names in Groovy

Tags: groovy

If I have a class named Character.groovy (with no explicit constructors) and try to instantiate it, I get a message that says:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.Character()
```

But if I change the class name to Characterr.groovy, then I am able to instantiate an object and use it as expected. So are there reserved words I can't use in Groovy classes? If so, why is Character one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reserved+Words
Those are the reserved keywords

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Character I believe is a object wrapper class in java which is why you can't use it. You can't use any name of java classes that are autoincluded in java

Comment: Thanks Joe, it must be the Java Character wrapper class I'm hitting.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a reserved class name, but there already is a class with that name (`java.lang.Character`) imported as the package `java.lang` gets imported automatically in java.

This can happen all the time, especially if you are a java developer and not used to get e.g. `java.io` package etc. autoimported for you by groovy (e.g. `File`) (see also [What packages does 1) Java and 2) Groovy automatically import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912400/what-packages-does-1-java-and-2-groovy-automatically-import))

There are three ways around it:

- the java way: address your class with the full name, that is package and class name.  e.g. `org.myrpg.Character`.
- the groovy way: import the class with a new name.  e.g. `import org.myrgp.Character as RPGChar` and use then `RPGChar` instead.
- the zen way: more often than not, it is not worth the hastle and easier to just rename your class. if you tripped over this once, then the chance very high you will trip over this again and only things like `@CompileStatic` or an IDE **may** make notice you this at compile time or while writing it.